# wordpress page template not loading as front page

Tags: wordpress

I have a page template set up as the front page but it's not loading for some reason. I've done this plenty of times in the past just fine.

I should be getting a body class of "portfolio-page-template" but rather I just get the regular "page-template".

I've tried resetting the permalinks, deleting/recreating the Portfolio page, changing back to the default theme and changing back, and still no dice.

Anybody know of a fix?

Answer (score 0):

Need more info.
Did you save it as home.php did you override it in the settings? http://img.lajlev.dk/5a842c1e3dc470468c322af0fe79c004.png

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem, and while it’s not an eloquent solution but when my working home page template started defaulting to my `taxonomy.php` template without reason, I tried all of the things you mention and then:

1. deleted the taxonomy template,
2. deleted the `.htacces` and refreshed the permalinks
3. selected and set the `page-template-home.php` again
4. noticed all was well
5. put my taxonomy template back and surprise  - everything worked

very strange.

If this is not your issue, I can give you a few pointers on what to check for when setting up a custom page template, and what to check for if it fails.

Answer (score -1):

Check the status of theme path or theme sittings